# trap divide error rip on 32 bit executable

Tags: linux, g++, 32bit-64bit, divide-by-zero

While I opened this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801854/trap-divide-error-rip-in-c-32-bit-program-runnig-on-64-bit-machine,
I have a question to ask you: why if my program in as 32 bit (g++ -m32) the error show me the RIP and not the EIP ??

*MYPROG[19817] trap divide error rip:bfee72 rsp:e116355c error:0*

p.s.
I'm working on linux machine

Thanks 
Federico